# Unable to resolve "expo-location" from "App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, geolocation, native

I keep getting this error: `iOS Bundling failed 52ms Unable to resolve expo-location from App.js`

And it just wont work pls help, im ripping my hair out

Thanks

I've installed expo constants and expo location and other needed modules

I had these lines in my code:

```
import { Constants } from 'expo-constants';
import * as LocationYES from 'expo-location';
```

nothing works pls help

Comment: Please add your list of dependencies from `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your app.json?

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use your location."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Expo docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/

*Rebuilding development client might solve your issue as well.*

Comment: Hi Thanks, Its now working i think i hadnt done npm install in the correct folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just needed to update  run npm i